# Bootstrap fileupload width change prevention

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using fileupload for Bootstrap fileupload my problem is when I upload file then filename display in a textbox but that textbox size change . How I can prevent this. I'm using this https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_custom_file&stacked=h in w3school. Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="custom-file mb-3 ">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" name="filename">
   <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
 </div>
```

Here is my JS code

```
$(".custom-file-input").on("change", function () {
    //$('.custom-file-input').css('width', '1000px');
    var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();

    $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
    //$('.custom-file-input').css('width', '1000px');
});
```

I examine and found this code is responsible for width change

```
$(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
```

How I can prevent this?

Here I upload image for for my problem for clarification:

[image]

Here after I upload file I got this fileupload width change:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to split the filename to fit it inside the box? or do you want the upload box width not to change?

Comment: add your HTML code here

Comment: I want to add the filename in box that is ok but box size changes that is problem

Comment: @Lalji Tadhani  I have given the HTML code which html you want

Comment: like (promotional text & time limit) HTML block

Comment: I think that is not important my task is  in here <div class="custom-file mb-3 ">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" name="filename">
   <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
 </div>

Comment: There have no task .

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the label width:

```
width: -webkit-fill-available;
```